# Add a function to return folder size in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am querying a drive for folder name/count/last modified.  However I would also like to add folder size MB.  I have searched/tried a few options but can't get them to work.

The file is also failing due to some paths being over 240char. Is there a workaround for this (eg skipping these folders)?

Grateful for help with a line of code that I would add.  Or any changes to below.
Many thanks.

```
$FOLDER_ROOT = "K:\Docs\"
$OUTPUT_LOCATION = "C:\Users\me\Documents\Powershell_OUT.txt"
Function DirX($directory)
{
    Remove-Item $OUTPUT_LOCATION

    foreach ($singleDirectory in (Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse -Directory))
    {
        $count = Get-ChildItem $singleDirectory.FullName -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
        $summary = $singleDirectory.FullName+"|"+$count+"|"+$singleDirectory.LastAccessTime
        Add-Content $OUTPUT_LOCATION $summary
    }
}
DirX($FOLDER_ROOT)
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/631092/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-folder-using-powershell

Comment: Regarding the path length issue, search for "MAX_PATH limit".

Comment: Thanks.  Would I add this in like this?                     

`$size = Get-ChildItem $singleDirectory | Measure-Object -property length -sum`

Comment: `$stats = Get-ChildItem $singleDirectory -File | Measure-Object -property length -sum` and then `$size = $stats.sum` and `$count = $stats.count`